# problems with libapache2-mod-php5.5.9 on Apache2/Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I've been given a task that requires me to learn PHP and Apache2. My issue is that I cannot seem to set up my dev environment correctly.

The PHP version I'm required to use is php5.5.9; which I believe I have got installed. I compiled and built the PHP5.5.9 package myself; I can see that this was successful by running:

```
$ php --version
  PHP 5.5.9 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2017 12:09:34) 
  Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

My issue now is that I cannot seem to get it to run on Apache2. I still consider myself somewhat of a novice to Linux, and as a result I'm pretty confused. When setting up higher versions of PHP, I just needed to run:

```
$ apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7
```

But the package for libapache2-mod-php5.5.9 is not present in any repo's that I've been able to find, and download from, so I assumed I needed, simply libapache2-mod-php5, which throws the following error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 fontconfig : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1)
              Depends: fontconfig-config but it is not going to be 
installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not     
going to be installed
                       Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.22) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: ucf but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: php5-cli but it is not going to be 
installed
 libblkid1 : Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be 
installed
 libfontconfig1 : Depends: fontconfig-config (= 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) 
but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk2.0-0 : Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going 
to be installed
               Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not 
going to be installed
               Depends: libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.28.3) but it is not 
going to be installed
               Recommends: libgtk2.0-bin
 libqt5svg5 : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.6~)
              Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.3.0) but it is not going 
to be installed
 libsm6 : Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be 
caused by held packages.
```

The only advice I've been able to find is to downgrade to Ubuntu 14.04, but this isn't possible at the moment because I'm in the process of loading a fully exported MySQL database to my machine; which has been going for hours, and I cannot see it being done any time soon. Since time is of value, is there any way around this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: My apologies I must have gotten confused. For anybody finding this in the future, I have reposted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400403/problems-with-libapache2-mod-php5-5-9-on-apache2-ubuntu-16-04).